# DiD with multiple overlapping windows

Tags: group-differences, generalized-did

I would like to set up a difference in difference model with multiple overlapping windows. The treatment group are firms located in a county hit by a hurricane while the control group includes all other firms in non-affected counties.
However my problem is that when trying to set up a control and treatment group by hurricane-cohort, some of the control firms in one hurricane-cohort tend to overlap with another hurricane-cohort.

My estimation window would be 24 quarters (12 before and 12 after) but most hurricanes happen every year and therefore some of the control firms could appear as controls for different treatment firms.
My question is:

1. Should I create sub-samples of hurricane-cohorts and then use a panel set up with county-cohort-quarter and then cluster my regressions at the cohort level. This would yield multiple duplicates of firm-quarter observations as controls in different groups.
2. Create a panel set up with unique firm-quarter, ignoring cohort, and then run the regressions based on a set up without acknowledging the existence of a cohort?

Also, should the panel data be setup such as each observation has exactly 24 quarters or are gaps ok (i.e. if less than 24 quarters exist it is ok to keep the firm in the sample)?